# No handler for type [geo-point] declared on field ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I'm attempting to map a field in my data as a `geo-point` so that I can visualize the data on a map in kibana. The data is stored as a string of coordinates (e.g. "12.35,48.64"). Below is how I've attempted to map the field.

```html
"latlong":{
  "type":"geo-point",
  "fields":{
    "raw":{
      "type":"keyword",
      "ignore_above":256
      }
    }
  },
```

I pulled code from `GET index/_mapping`, then altered the type to `geo-point`, then I get the error

> "type": "mapper_parsing_exception",
>       "reason": "Failed to parse mapping [docs]: No handler for type [geo-point] declared on field [latlong]",

Any help is appreciated. I'm brand-new to elasticsearch, so it's probably an easy fix.

Answer (score 5):

It turned out to be syntax:

`geo-point` should have been `geo_point`

Then I got rid of the rest of the fluff:

```
"latlong":{
   "type":"geo_point"
},
```

Now it displays beautifully in Kibana.